# ArcGIS JavaScript 3.28 extent not working

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, extents

I'm trying to get an extent to work on a web map app but keep getting an error when trying to pass the extent parameter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require([
              "esri/map",
              "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
              "dojo/domReady!",
              "esri/geometry/Extent", 
              "esri/SpatialReference"], 
      function(
              Map,
              FeatureLayer,
              Extent,
              SpatialReference
              ) {

      var extent = new esri.geometry.Extent(-121.467,37.454,-122.3737,37.9067, new SpatialReference({ wkid:4326 }));

        map = new Map("map", {
          extent: extent,
          basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
          center: [-121.91, 37.65], // longitude, latitude 
          zoom: 10
        });

      var countyBoundary = new FeatureLayer("https://services5.arcgis.com/ROBnTHSNjoZ2Wm1P/arcgis/rest/services/County_Boundary/FeatureServer/0");
      map.addLayer(countyBoundary);


      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error returned is:

```
a.equals is not a function
```

And is happening right at `map = new Map("map", {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in the order of the dojo require statements.

The following order is the right one, putting the domReady at the end:

```
   require([
      "esri/map",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",                 
      "esri/geometry/Extent", 
      "esri/SpatialReference",
      "dojo/domReady!",], 
  function(
      Map,
      FeatureLayer,
      Extent,
      SpatialReference
  ) {
```

And your code will be the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require([
              "esri/map",
              "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",                 
              "esri/geometry/Extent", 
              "esri/SpatialReference",
              "dojo/domReady!",], 
      function(
              Map,
              FeatureLayer,
              Extent,
              SpatialReference
              ) {

      var extent = new Extent(-121.467,37.454,-122.3737,37.9067, new SpatialReference({ wkid:4326 }));

        map = new Map("map", {
          extent: extent,
          basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
          center: [-121.91, 37.65], // longitude, latitude 
          zoom: 10
        });

      var countyBoundary = new FeatureLayer("https://services5.arcgis.com/ROBnTHSNjoZ2Wm1P/arcgis/rest/services/County_Boundary/FeatureServer/0");
      map.addLayer(countyBoundary);


      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: Also consider to remove the center and the zoom if you are passing an extent to the Map constructor.

Comment: Thanks Katah. It seems that this only loads the map on the extent specified and doesn't actually bound the map to that extent. I'm trying to find a way to implement a bounding box so users cannot pan beyond the extents of a county border. The code, however, is working with your solution, that is, I'm not getting any errors. Unfortunately it's not the right code to implement a bounding box.

Comment: I think you cannot avoid that directly. An Idea is to connect to the `onExtentChange` event and modify the extent accordingly.
There is also a map property called [GeographicExtent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#geographicextent), but I didn't test it.